# jQuery Flexslider not working in iphone and ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I need to remove class from li tag when i click or tap on the navigation arrow in flexslider. It is working perfectly in all my browsers but i can't able to produce the same in iphone and ipad.when i click on navigation arrow slider moves correctly using flexslider plugin code but alert in my code comes rarely not continuously

```
 $(".flex-direction-nav a.flex-next,.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev").on('click', 'tap', function () {
    alert("hi");        
    $(".repeat-cont li.active-slide.open").removeClass("open");
});
```

Do you have any special properties for mobile or any idea on this code?I tried touchstart instead of tap.

Answer (score 0):

The two events should be combined like `"click tap"` instead of `"click", "tap"`:

```
$(".flex-direction-nav a.flex-next,.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev").on('click tap', function () {
    alert("hi");        
    $(".repeat-cont li.active-slide.open").removeClass("open");
});
```

Also, be sure you are using jquery mobile if you are using `tap()`

Comment: Thanks derek,it works after i replace touchstart instead of tap